# nested if statement in C#

Tags: c#, if-statement, statements

I get the command prompt to come up and get the correct answer for Bad Score, but if I try to type in a good grade (800) it does nothing. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am new to this so I apologize my coder isn't pretty.

```
        //variables
        string firstName, lastName, grades = "";
        double points = 0, percent = 0;


        //Greeting
        Console.WriteLine("The purpose of this program is to allow the teacher to calculate the percentage and final grade for students in their class.");

        //Display and Inputs
        Console.WriteLine("\n\nPlease enter the students first name.");
        firstName = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("\n\nPlease enter the students last name.");
        lastName = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("\n\nPlease enter the points that the student received.\n\n");
        points = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

        //Display after points are entered
        if (points < 0 || points > 1000 ) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Bad Score!");
        }
        else 
        {
            percent = points / 1000;
            if (percent >= .9)
            {
                grades = "A";
            }
            else if (percent >= .8)
            {
                grades = "B";
            }
            if (percent >= .7)
            {
                grades = "C";
            }
            else if (percent >= .6)
            {
                grades = "D";
            }
            if (percent >= .0)
            {
                grades = "F";
            }
            else
            {
                 Console.WriteLine("WRONG!!");
            }
        }               
        grades = Console.ReadLine();

        //Outputs
        Console.WriteLine(firstName); 
        Console.WriteLine(lastName);
        Console.WriteLine(points);
        Console.WriteLine(percent.ToString("P"));
        Console.WriteLine("so they made an" + grades);

        //Closing statement
        Console.WriteLine("Goodbye");
        Environment.Exit(1);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: 1) Align the `if/else if` lines to the left, directly under each other, *and*; 2) put a blank line before every line starting with `if` - *a* problem should become clear (and is a good exercise to fix).

Comment: if you are giving 800 nothing is printing??

Comment: probably best to use a switch statement here rather then all if... else if statements. The program has to run through all if's until it reaches the correct one. A switch statement only tests once and goes straight to the correct case. Much more efficient.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a bunch of problems

1. You are missing an `else` before the 'C' and 'F' branches. Currently, all positive grades will become 'F's

   ```
   else if (percent >= .7)
   {
       grades = "C";
   }
   ```

And again

```
    else if (percent >= .0)
    {
        grades = "F";
    }
```

2. You are then overwriting your calculated grades with this line

```
 grades = Console.ReadLine();
```

I believe you may have intended:

```
Console.WriteLine(grades);
```

3. Your app will exit after the calculation. I suggest a `Console.ReadLine` at or similar at the end to allow the user to view the results

Answer (score 1):

1. Suppose you enter

first name - Puneet
last name - Chawla
Enter the points students received - 
800
10

Then answer is

Puneet
Chawla
800
80.00 %
so they made an10
Goodbye

2. When this condition will be false if (points < 0 || points > 1000) then you are giving grade according to percent i think, you don't need to get grade again from user.
3. In some conditions, wrong output can come because you have set
   Wrong -  if,elseif, if,elseif,if then else
   Correct - if,elseif,elseif,elseif,elseif then else.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the `grades` variable correcty. But at the end of the ifs statements you are overriding its value, so just remove this line:

```
grades = Console.ReadLine();
```

PS: Also you could chain all `if`s statements with `else if`

Answer (score 0):

Your pgms have two problems at first glance

1. Your `if..else` is wrong inside the `else` it should be

   `else 
           {
               percent = points / 1000;
               if (percent >= .9)
               {
                   grades = "A";
               }
               else if (percent >= .8)
               {
                   grades = "B";
               }
               else if (percent >= .7)
               {
                   grades = "C";
               }
               else if (percent >= .6)
               {
                   grades = "D";
               }
               else if (percent >= .0)
               {
                   grades = "F";
               }
               else
               {
                    Console.WriteLine("WRONG!!");
               }
           }`

you are missing else at checking if percent >= 0.7 and percent >=.0
let say you entered 800 so percentage will be 0.8 so the condition if percent >=.08 will be true and grade ="B" and since there is no else at percent >= 0.7 it will also pass and grade will become  "c" atlast there is no else while checking percent >= .0 so it will also pass and grade will become "F" so else is needed in all condition. So finally what ever the positive percentage is there the grade will be "F" because of missing else..in the if conditions

2. you should remove `grade = Consolde.ReadLine();` because it will overwrite your assign in grade.

Comment: Thank you so much! This has been driving me crazy